Stackelberg Model with inseparable variables: How to find sequential equilibrium?
I have a leader who has to optimise quantity, x, inputting the quantity of follower, y.
Problem is quantity equation of leader and follower are not separable.
Leader's objective function is -
$$ \sqrt{x} (y^3 - y^2) + \sqrt{1-x} (y^2 - 2y)$$
Follower's best response function is -
$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{x} y^3 - \sqrt{1-x} ~ 3y}{\sqrt{x} (y-1)^4 - \sqrt{1-x} y^2} $$
If I substitute y into leader's objective function and differentiate wrt x. I'll get differential equation (with dy/dx) and setting it equal to 0
Is this the right way to approach this problem? Is there a better way? Please help.
For reference, Attached is the differentiation of leader's objective function, after substituting x, wrt y


Hi Elina, is it possible to post the quation in Tex and not as pic? Thank you

I have just posted the differential equation as Pic, because it is not directly related to my question. I want to know the idea with which I am doing, is it correct or is there a better way to approach this. Thank you for looking at my problem. Can you please give your insights @T123

"Follower's best response function" should be "objective function", right?

Sorry for confusion @VARulle. Follower's best response function is solution of y after optimizing its objective function, taking x as given

There is simply no reason to include the image. Can you explain what use you think any reader will have for it?

Sequential equilibrium is not really defined for games with a continuum of actions.

@MichaelGreinecker No, sequential equilibrium is defined for continuum of action. Stackelberg game is a perfect example of it

@Giskard I included because the image shows that solving for x requires solving differential equation. If there is a better approach than this, I am asking for guidance on that

@ElinaGilbert Sure: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912767
